# Multithreading in spacy v3.0

Tags: multithreading, cython, spacy, spacy-3

I'm trying to use spacy to train a named entity recogniser and it seems to be using only one thread. I did some research and it seems to be a Cython and GIL problem with a way to change the number of threads located in the 'pipe' method. I also found this very useful article: https://explosion.ai/blog/multithreading-with-cython

The problem is this is written for spacy v2 and v3.0 completely changed their format with config files and whatnot. I'm using Linux on a machine with 8 threads. How would I successfully multithread with spacy v3.0?

Answer (score 2):

Multithreading is not supported as of spacy v2. The current alternative is to use ray for distributed training with the package `spacy-ray`: https://spacy.io/usage/training#parallel-training